# Xuggler - Getting snapshots from RTMP stream

Tags: java, ffmpeg, xuggler

I'm using the last xuggler lib on Java 7 (MacOs Maverix).
I need to get a

png snapshot from a live rtmp stream served by wowza.

For this I'm using the default com.xuggle.xuggler.demos.DecodeAndCaptureFrames.
There are some problems:

1. reader.readPacket() has a delay of ~5 minutes (it seems xuggler tries to buffer or guess the format, difficult to explain)
2. After this delay, some external process starts (I guess it's ffmpeg) and my CPU usage is 100%.
3. In parallel with high CPU load, I see the png files created correctly, but after 2-3 minutes I get always the following exception

   14:40:35.785 [main] ERROR org.ffmpeg - WriteN, RTMP send error 32 (14 bytes)
   14:40:35.790 [main] ERROR org.ffmpeg - WriteN, RTMP send error 32 (42 bytes)

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution: I had to manually set the **probesize** property on **IContainer** to 2048 and it works.